# How to parse JSON in Spring Boot Application automatically using Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa, jackson

I have **json file** **with json object** as value of property inside:

```
{
 "name": "name",
 "json": {...}
}
```

I need to get it **automatically** in **RestController** and use it as entity in **JPA+Hibernate**.

My entity is:

**UPDATE -> more specified entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "collections")
public class Collection {
    @Id
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "cache_limit")
    private int limit;

    @Column(name = "cache_algorithm")
    private String algorithm;

    @Transient
    private JsonNode schema;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name ="json_schema")
    private String jsonSchema;

    public Collection() {
    }

    public String getJsonSchema() {
        return schema.toString();
    }

    public void setJsonSchema(String jsonSchema) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            schema = mapper.readTree(jsonSchema);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Parsing error -> String to JsonNode");
        }
    }

   ..setters and getters for name limit algorithm schema..
}
```

When I use `entityManager.persist(Collection)` I have `json_schema` column as **NULL**

**How can I solve It?** The problem is in **setJsonSchema()** perhaps

**update**:

```
public String getJsonSchema() {
        return jsonSchema;
    }

    public void setJsonSchema(JsonNode schema) {
        this.jsonSchema = schema.toString();
    }
```

Such getters/setters don't solve the problem

Comment: What do you mean by "json field would be empty."? Your controller looks like `Cat getCat(int name){ return cats.getCatByName(name);}` and it returns `JSON` object with `name` and `json` property is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define `JsonNode json` property as `@Transient` so JPA does not try to store it on database. However, jackson should be able to translate it back and forward to Json.

Then you can code getter/setter for JPA, so you translate from JsonNode to String back and forward. You define a getter `getJsonString` that translate `JsonNode json` to `String`. That one can be mapped to a table column, like 'json_string', then you define a setter where you receive the `String` from JPA and parse it to JsonNode that will be avaialable for jackson.

Do not forget to add `@JsonIgnore` to `getJsonString` so Jackson does not try to translate to json as jsonString.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cats")
public class Cat {

  private Long id;

  private String name;

  @Transient
  private JsonNode json;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  @Column(name ="name")
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  // Getter and setter for name

  @Transient
  public JsonNode getJson() {
    return json;
  }

  public void setJson(JsonNode json) {
    this.json = json;
  }


  @Column(name ="jsonString")
  public String getJsonString() {
    return this.json.toString();
  }

  public void setJsonString(String jsonString) {
    // parse from String to JsonNode object
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
      this.json = mapper.readTree(jsonString);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a bit strange, but json.asText() doesn't work. json.toString() works

Comment: When i use JPA this @JsonIgnore column is NULL

Comment: Can you debug and see what is the value of json on get/setJsonString?

Comment: get/setJsonString work correctly. After using entityManager.persist(cat) i have NULL in database

Comment: I can remove @Column(name ="json_string") - the result would be the same

Comment: I did update the code, can you try that one? It seems JPA looks for consistency on columns declaration. Either @/Column should be at attributes level or at getter method. Since we were using a mix of both, setters where ignored. If we define setters for all attributes and mark them with @/Columns it should work

Comment: I updated new code example, the problem realy is in using setter for String column but I am still solving It

Comment: I noticed you added jsonSchema attribute which is never set. Probable JPA access the attribute using reflection to persist it into database. So, getter and setter is never executed and json object never pared to a string.

Comment: So using @JsonIgnore is impossible to use JPA?

Comment: You need to remove that jsonSchema attribute. Them mové all your column annotations to your getter methods, for all of the columns including ID. (I tested this in my side)

Comment: It finally works! I am very greateful, thank you one more time

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-store-schema-less-eav-entity-attribute-value-data-using-json-and-hibernate/), you don't have to create a custom Hibernate Type manually since you can simply get it via Maven Central using the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-types.version}</version> 
</dependency>
```

For more info, check out the [Hibernate Types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types/) open-source project.

Then you can simply declare the new type you class.

```
@TypeDef(
    name = "jsonb-node", 
    typeClass = JsonNodeBinaryType.class
)
```

And the entity mapping will look like this:

```
@Type(type = "json-node")
@Column(columnDefinition = "json")
private JsonNode json;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create response without putting logic into entity setter/getter, without third party dependencies:

```
ObjectNode node = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
node.put("name", cat.getName());
node.set("json", new ObjectMapper().readTree(cat.getJson()));
return Response.ok(node).build();
```